# ASP.Net WebAPI with Angularjs 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have made this project using this [Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/48d928e3-9b5c-4faf-b46f-d6baa7d9886c"this text appears when you mouse over").

It is a simple task manager, where you can create, complete, and delete a task.

I got it up and running and added an extra button, by almost completely copying the template author's code.

I following code is an example of his method and my method.

**CODE**

His way to complete a task:

frontend:

```
// called by ng-click="complete($index)"
$scope.complete = function(index)
    {
        $http.post('/api/WS_Todo/CompleteTodoItem/' + $scope.todoList[index].id)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.getList();
            });
    }
```

backend:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    async public Task<HttpResponseMessage> CompleteTodoItem(int id)
    {
        var item = db.todos.Where(t => t.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.completed = true;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

My way to reopen a task:

frontend:

```
// called by ng-click="reopen($index)"  
$scope.reopen = function(index)
    {
        $http.post('/api/WS_Todo/ReopenTodoItem', +$scope.todoList[index].id)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.getList();
                });
    }
```

backend:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    async public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReopenTodoItem(int id)
    {
        var item = db.todos.Where(t => t.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.completed = false;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

His code works as intended.

My code gives me:

POST http://localhost:33651/api/WS_Todo/ReopenTodoItem 404 (Not Found)     angularjs:9734

And i can't see how the routing should be a problem when both methods are in the same frontent and backend controller.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would specify a route attribute on my webApi method:

```
[Route("/api/WS_Todo/CompleteTodoItem/{id}")]
```

And call the url from the front with the proper syntax.
Same for the other methods.

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't just about getting it to work, i wish to understand why it doesn't work. Could you spread any light on that?

Comment: I assume it doesn't make the matching between your controller method signature and the route you are calling from the front. It's often due to the method arguments naming or the $http.post route syntax, so you should try to specify a straight route, and call it exactly as it's specified.

Comment: Ok you still dont get it, His code works. my 90% identical code does not work. I can find no errors in my controller names, methods, URL's routing or anything. and yes, of course it is a problem of the matching between the front and backend, but my question remains, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

And after several attempts different approaches.. i was beaten by a comma in my url >.<